# I need help setting up how to fetch and send accessToken between my backend and frontend MERN apps hosted on render and netlify respectively

Tags: reactjs, node.js, es6-modules

I get the error: "You are not authenticated!" from my middleware below when a logged in user tries to make request to protected backend route through the middleware.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import User from "../models/user.model.js";
import createError from "../utils/createError.js";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {

  const token = req.cookies.accessToken;

  console.log('Token:', token);
  if (!token) return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));


  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, async (err, payload) => {

    console.log('Payload:', payload);

    if (err) {
      console.error('JWT Verification Error:', err);
      return next(createError(403, 'Token is not valid!'));
    }

    try {
      if (payload.id) {
        const user = await User.findById(payload.id);
        if (!user) {
          return next(createError(404, "User not found!"));
        }
        req.user = user;
        req.userId = user._id; // Set the userId in the req object
      }

      // Allow the request to continue if it's from a logged-in user
      if (req.user) {
        next();
      } else {
        return next(createError(403, "Unauthorized access!"));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
      return next(createError(500, "Failed to fetch user data!"));
    }
  });
};
```

I have tried to retrieve the accessToken set as a cookie in my frontend when the user logs in before they make a request to my backend but that also doesn't work. In my frontend using the code below returns "undefined" for the console log of "cookie" :

```
    const cookie = document.Cookies;
     
        console.log("document.cookie:", cookie);

       // Check if document.cookie exists and is not undefined or null
         if (cookie) {
          const token = cookie
          .split("; ")
           .find((row) => row.startsWith("accessToken"))
             ?.split("=")[1];

           const token = Cookies.get("accessToken");
```

How can i retrieve my accessToken stored as a cookie in my frontend?